# Expected number of moves of a random walk inside a simplex

Tags: probability, random-walk, dice

Few days ago,  Roger Blazey, retired head maths teacher, at LinkedIn group told about the following problem:

> “This problem was raised as part of a lecture at The Biennial AAMT (Australian Association of Mathematics Teachers) in Sydney in 1972. In 1972 I was a young, beginning Mathematics Teacher. The lecture was given, I think, by a Professor RADE , and if my memory serves me well, the Title of his Lecture, in one of the many plenary sessions was, "Stochastic Processes."
>
> The simplicity of the result for the basic problem, fascinated me then and nothing has changed for me today!
>
> Here is the problem, in it's most basic form.
>
> ”On a table there are $2$ piles of disks... $4$ disks in one pile (pile $A$) and $3$ disks in the other pile (pile $B$). So based on the outcome resulting in the throw of a coin ($H$ or $T$) .....................................
>
> when a head occurs, a disk is transferred from $A$ to $B$; otherwise (for a tail) a disk is transferred from $B$ to $A$. What is the expected number of moves to have either $A$ or $B$ void?
>
> Now computer modelling will quickly suggest a result of $12$ with the strong suspicion that when $n(A)=x$ and $n(B)=y$ the expected number of moves is given by “$xy$”.
>
> So how can this be proved?
>
> The obvious extension (which, to my knowledge was not raised by anyone at the lecture) is, “what is the formula for $3$ piles of disks and the outcome on the fall of a die.... And further for $4$ piles of disks, $5$ piles,............ “$p$” piles of disks?"
>
> The formula for $3$ piles of disk (numbering $x$, $y$ and $z$) is certainly not the product "$xyz$"
>
> Hymn ... a tad too difficult for me I'm afraid! Over to you!”

[Here](https://lnkd.in/bhTA43x) is the link to the discussion at LinkedIn.

*My try.* It seems the following.

Let $x=n(A)$, $y=n(B)$, $x+y=N=\operatorname{const}$, and $E(x;N)$ be the expected number of moves to have either $A$ or $B$ void.

Then we obtain the following boundary and recurrent formulas for $E(x;N)$:

$E(0;N)=E(N;N)=0$ (there is no need to move) and if $0<x<N$ then $$E(x;N)=1+(E(x+1;N)+E(x-1;N))/2.$$

(By the symmetry, $E(N-x;N)=E(x;N)$, but we shall not need this in the following proof).

The recurrent formula can be transformed to

$$E(x+1;N)=2E(x;N)-E(x-1;N)-2$$

which solution for $x\ge 1$ is

$$E(x;N)=xE(1;N)-x^2+x.$$

Since $E(N;N)=0$ we obtain $NE(1;N)-N^2+N=0.$

So $E(1;N)=N-1$ and $E(x;N)=x(N-x)=xy.$

The general problem can be interpreted as a random motion inside a simplex

$$\{x_1,\dots,x_k\ge 0 : x_1+\dots+x_k=N\}$$

with respective boundary and recurrent conditions.

So, this is the problem. The two piles  case was simple and we have a luck to obtain a nice little neat answer here (although Roger disagreed  with me :-) ) . But the case of more than two piles seems to be much more hard and need to involve methods which are far beyond the simple observations which I used to solve two piles case. I googled for a general case and found none. But I found a couple of similar problems, which are hard and use complicated techniques to investigate: Bruce Hajek “[Gambler's Ruin: A Random Walk on the Simplex](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4612-4808-8_56#)” and [Wikipedia remark on N-player gamblers ruin problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin#N-player_ruin_problem).

Roger wrote:

> I would like to think there is a formula for 3 piles of disks and perhaps if Dr. Alan Turing were alive today he would derive a result for it!

But because an invocation of a spirit of Dr. Alan Turing is not an easy task, I hope that participants of MSE will found an other way to solve this problem. :-)

Comment: PS. There is already a lot of questions related to two piles case. For instance

Comment: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553690/expected-number-of-steps-in-a-random-walk-with-a-boundary),[2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307187/expected-number-of-steps-till-a-random-walk-hits-a-or-b),[3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288298/symmetric-random-walk-with-bounds?rq=1),[4](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324109/probability-what-is-the-average-number-of-steps?lq=1),
[5](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249546/average-number-of-flips-for-someone-to-win?rq=1),[6](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609995/probability-ruin-problem?rq=1)

Comment: Mircea Grecu just pointed to me a publication “[A matrix-analytic approach to the N-player ruin problem](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38350944_A_matrix-analytic_approach_to_the_N-player_ruin_problem)” by Yvik C. Swan and F. Thomas Bruss

Comment: With 3 piles A, B, C, what is the move when the die selects pile A?

Comment: @Did I thought about it. :-) Roger did not provided a complete description of a generalization, so I think we may assume that each of six moves $A\to B$, $B\to A$, $A\to C$, $C\to A$, $B\to C$,  and $C\to B$ has an equal probability $1/6$.

Answer (score 2):

> Assume 3 piles of disks and that at each step a disk passes from one pile to another, the 6 possible choices of the "emitting" pile and of the "receiving" pile are equiprobable. Then the mean time for some pile to be empty, starting from piles of heights $x$, $y$, $z$, is $$\frac{3xyz}{x+y+z}.$$

To prove this, note that the function $$t:(x,y,z)\mapsto xyz,$$ defined on the nonnegative integers $(x,y,z)$ such that $x+y+z=n$ for some given $n$, is such that $t(x,y,z)=0$ if $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$ and, for every positive $(x,y,z)$, $$t(x,y,z)=\tfrac13n+\tfrac16(t(x,y+1,z-1)+t(x,y-1,z+1)+t(x+1,y,z-1)+t(x-1,y,z+1)+t(x+1,y-1,z)+t(x-1,y+1,z)).$$ The uniqueness of the solutions of Pascal equation makes that $\frac3nt(x,y,z)$ is indeed the mean exit time from the triangle, starting from $(x,y,z)$.

For more on the subject, see [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.5142).

Note that for 4 piles of disks the mean time for some pile to be empty is *not* a multiple of the product of their heights.